# Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!doctype "... is not valid JSON only for get requests

Tags: reactjs, node.js, vite

I am getting this error while fetching from get route from my node server.I can succesfully make post requests.I have used zustand for routing:

```
import { create } from "zustand";

const useConversation = create((set) => ({
    selectedConversation: null,
    setSelectedConversation: (selectedConversation) => set({ selectedConversation }),
    messages: [],
    setMessages: (messages) => set({ messages }),
}));

export default useConversation;
```

the error:

```
localhost/:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!doctype "... is not valid JSON
useGetConversations.js:16
```

The error seems to be in following file:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import toast from "react-hot-toast";

const useGetConversations = () => {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [conversations, setConversations] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const getConversations = async () => {
            setLoading(true);
            try {
                
                
                const res = await fetch("/users");

                console.log(res);//the res is printed in console with bodyUsed as true
                
                const data = await res.json();//this is never executed ig
               
                if (data.error) {
                    throw new Error(data.error);
                }
                setConversations(data);
            } catch (error) {
                toast.error(error.message);
            } finally {
                setLoading(false);
            }
        };

        getConversations();
    }, []);

    return { loading, conversations };
};

export default useGetConversations;
```

I have already check for following:
1.Vite configrations to interact with api:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  server: {
        port: 3000,
        proxy: {
            "/api": {
                target: 'http://localhost:5000',
                changeOrigin: true,
                 secure: false
            },
        },
    },
})
```

2. I tried putting log statements in routes in my backend, It gets printed for post routes but for get routes it doesn't get executed. My guess is its not making the fetch call for some reason.
3. I also tried the get request using postman and it returns a success with json object.

Comment: The response starts with `<!doctype ` and that is not JSON. I'm repeating the error message, but that is really it. The call `res.json()` expects JSON, but it gets HTML.

Comment: Give you're only proxying paths that start with `/api`, shouldn't you be using `fetch('/api/users')`?

Comment: @Phil Thanks a lot! It worked for me ,I just changed the routing on my backend from "/users" to "/api/users" . It was something minor and I was racking my brains for hours

Answer (score -1):

My issue is already solved,helped by @Phil . I just changed my routing on my backend from "/users" to "/api/users".
It was because I was only proxing paths with "/api" on my vite.config.js file.

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  server: {
        port: 3000,
        proxy: {
            "/api": { //here it is
                target: 'http://localhost:5000',
                changeOrigin: true,
                 secure: false
            },
        },
    },
})
```